# Assign to null reference type

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, null, pass-by-reference

Please understand that I see and follow the issue, but am unsure of how to resolve it cleanly. I am trying to run my **Add** method, iterate until my key is either found or the current node is null, then return the *reference* to the node and assign if it is null. My code (see comment in the add method):

```
public class MyClass<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Node _baseNode;

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        var newNode = new Node(key, value);

        //this returns null, as is expected.
        var nodeToUpdate = TraverseDown(ref _baseNode, newNode.Key);

        if (nodeToUpdate != null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add a duplicate key.");

        //here, I try to assign a value to _baseNode because I'd like
        //nodeToUpdate to hold the reference to _baseNode
        nodeToUpdate = newNode;
    }

    private Node TraverseDown(ref Node currentNode, int keyToFind)
    {
        if (currentNode == null || currentNode?.Key == keyToFind 
            || currentNode?.Edge == null)
        {
            //on first add, this is what is getting hit - as expected
            return currentNode;
        }
        else
        {
            //these are being explicitly set to local variables because i was 
            //experimenting with passing them byRef, and that can't be done on 
            //properties
            var leftNode = currentNode.Edge.LeftNode;
            var rightNode = currentNode.Edge.RightNode;
            return keyToFind < currentNode.Key 
                            ? TraverseDown(ref leftNode, keyToFind) 
                            : TraverseDown(ref rightNode, keyToFind);
        }
    }
}
```

The entire point of having the TraverseDown method accept a Node *byRef* is to try to return the reference to whatever node has been found, even if it is null. In this case, this is the first item being added, so the TraverseDown method should be returning the reference to my _baseNode, null be default. This however, simply sets the local variable to newNode, and _baseNode remains null.

I'm sure there is an easy answer for this, but I've been researching for a little bit and found nothing. Please, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no line in your `TraverseDown` method where you actually assign the `ref currentNode`. Instead you return its value. When you pass a `ref` parameter, it doesn't mean that the value will be treated as a reference throughout the method's scope. The *parameter itself* will be treated as a reference, not its value. So when you write...

```
return currentNode;
```

You return the *value* of `currentNode`, not the reference. Since the value is `null`, you always return `null` (because of your `if (currentNode == null...` statement).

When you assign...

```
nodeToUpdate = newNode;
```

...you simply assign a `null` reference.

When you actually want to assign a value to `_baseNode` in `TraverseDown`, you need to set `currentNode` within the method:

```
currentNode = //Value
```

Note that [in C# 7.0 there will be ref returns](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/), which behave in a way you are treating `currentNode` in your method.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, this makes perfect sense. Just read through the C# 7.0 link, some interesting stuff in there.

I guess this is operating as expected, but complicates how the code must be written. I need the `TraverseDown` method to just perform the search, not assignment. Think this means that I'll just explicitly have to set the top node in the add method, and from thereon probably return the parent node, not the node that I want to act upon directly. Unless you've got any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @Switch386, passing as a reference doesn't make much sense if you don't let the method make the assignment. If you don't weant to do that, it would indeed make more sense to return the node you want to add the new child to (ie. the new parent node).